# How to send the next GET Request?

Tags: php

Through the browser the request is sent (200),

But through PHP its fails (no data), How to send correctly?

```
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'proxy'=>"$proxy",
'header'=> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0".
       "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate".
       "Accept: */*"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url2 = "http://50.7.195.2:25461/live/***/***/6089.m3u8?token=HxZZBUsLRgMaAAAIUwpWAwcMCgUGWg8OAwBTCwBWVQFVDFBQXFoADFpEHBIRRkJRBFRnWVQbAw5VW18UFkdEABZrWAAaWUYNAVcCCEAeEkAMVF0SCgkVGhUKAhoOEAZVUw0CRhRBAUFMA0JeA15vUABPUVNVGwNWEA8KFBZdWToAUVwFVgdGAxpWEhxAW0NERwMaeRB/WEsRLQNMFH5jIUYYEwZRFxZYTAMSCkADBw1XGxQSU1ZMVhERHxoOEHAnRhgTAUAXAVdLD19eQAgSWVZMABIcG1BLOhEDS0BAUgQJUUNGAkFUGxREXVEabVNbC1ddU0RQVlYWQVwaBRAbRwlbXw1MDBZmSA9UElgQAQNdDgsSTQ==";
$data = file_get_contents($url2, false, $context);
echo data;
```

Comment: I assume what ever that ip is has cookies set from a browser and not there. Could even be user agent based. Most modern browsers allow you to copy a request as curl. When you do that you should see something you missed

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some EOLs (`\r\n`) after each header. Your `header` context is now one long concatenated string instead of several distinct headers.

Change it to this:

```
'header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0\r\n" .
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n" .
    "Accept: */*\r\n"
```